# Accessing a config variable on heroku returns a 500 error

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have tested and set a config variable to heroku for my flask app using the following code:

```
api = os.environ.get['API_KEY']
```

Testing it on foreman seems to work, but returns a 500 internal server error when deployed on heroku. Would the error be caused by the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is off. [`os.environ` is a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ). So,

```
api = os.environ.get['API_KEY']
```

should either be

```
api = os.environ['API_KEY'] #Would raise exception if key is not found
```

or

```
api = os.environ.get('API_KEY')
```